# Foundation Tabs Href

Tags: jquery, html, css, zurb-foundation

Is there a way that when you do a redirect on a Href this way href="contact/#orderTab", you could when the page loads, toggle the tab orderTab straight away ?

```
div class="medium-3 columns account-menu">
    <dl id="accountTabs" class="tabs vertical full plain" data-tab>
        <dd class="active"><a href="#detailsTab" id="my-account-details"><i class="fa fa-male fa-fw"></i> My Details</a></dd>
        <? if($has_account): ?>
        <dd><a href="#profileTab" id="my-account-profile"><i class="fa fa-user fa-fw"></i> My Profile</a></dd>
        <dd><a href="#locationTab" id="my-account-location"><i class="fa fa-map-marker fa-fw"></i> My Location</a></dd>
        <? endif ?>
        <dd><a href="#favouritesTab" id="my-account-favourites"><i class="fa fa-star fa-fw"></i> My Favourites</a></dd>
        <dd><a href="#ordersTab" id="my-account-orders"><i class="fa fa-credit-card fa-fw"></i> Orders &amp; Payment Info</a></dd>
        <? if($has_account): ?>
        <dd><a href="#membershipTab" id="my-account-membership"><i class="fa fa-info-circle fa-fw"></i> Membership Details</a></dd>
        <? endif ?>
        <dd><a href="#helpTab" id="my-account-help"><i class="fa fa-question-circle fa-fw"></i> Help &amp; Support</a></dd>
    </dl>
</div>
```

The redirect is here :

```
<a class="button" href="<?= root_url('account/#ordersTab') ?>">Return to the order list</a>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I actually found the answer which is adding data-options="deep_linking: true" to the UL.

This will allow the auto toggle depending on the URL, if the value after the # matches a tab, the tab will get the active class on it.